# uWSGI fails to install on Windows

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm trying to install uWSGI on Windows using `pip install uwsgi`  and it keeps failing with the bellow error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\fathima\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-igkqn2\uwsgi\
```

Answer (score 8):

The easy fix which i find was to download and modify configurations

[Download this stable lts release of uWSGI](https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.19.1.tar.gz)

Then after extracting, quickly navigate to the path where this file is available 'uwsgiconfig.py' open it.

Do the following changes:

```
import platform
```

and then wherever you encounter `os.uname()[x-index]` replace it with `platform.uname()[x-index]`

finally open the terminal/cmd in the working path and run
'python setup.py install' (make sure you have gcc installed & configured)

Answer (score 6):

uWSGI is implemented in C, and the version on PyPI is source only - no binaries are provided. To install it, you'll need to build it yourself, and according to the [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SupportedPlatforms.html?highlight=windows) only building with Cygwin is supported.