# uwsgi can't be installed

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I'm stuck trying to install uWSGI to deploy my Django application using **pip install uwsgi**, but encounter this error:

[image]

I've found several answers that unfortunately didn't work for me, like ***update dev tool*** ,***install cywin*** or modify ***uwsgiconfig.py*** (which doesn't exist since it's not installed ), or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: i would recommend just using nginx + gunicorn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uWSGI fails to install on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268566/uwsgi-fails-to-install-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the install cygwin attempt, did you also select the python3-devel package? os is only available for linux and not Windows which uses platform.

For the modify uwsgiconfig.py file, you can manually download it from [here](https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.19.1.tar.gz) and then modify to replace all instances of os.uname() with platform.uname()