# ERROR : metadata-generation-failed while installing uwsgi

Tags: python, html, django, flask, web-development-server

using the command
`pip install uwsgi`
it gave the error : metadata-generation-failed

i was tring to install a WSGI web server for flask,

`pip install uwsgi`
and install web server, i needed,
And to get thorough the installing functonal webserver for my flask app

Comment: The correct way: `py -m pip install uWSGI` Released: Feb 8, 2024

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71092850/how-to-install-uwsgi-on-windows